# add adjusted p value to ggplot with comparison

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I need help to add the adjusted p value (bonferroni for example) on ggplot boxplot instead of p value. I've try to do it with `stat_compare_means` from ggpub package by using `..p.adj..` on the aesthetics, but it doesn't work when I add the comparison list.

```
ggplot(data= mydf, aes(x=B,y=A)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  stat_compare_means(aes(label=..p.adj..),
                     comparisons = list(c("x","y"),c("x","z"),c("y","z")))
```

[image: boxplot]

Answer (score 0):

How about this;

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
mydf <- data.frame(A=1:300, B=rep(c("x","y","z"),100))
my_comparisons<- list(c("x","y"),c("x","z"),c("y","z"))

p<- ggplot(data= mydf, aes(x=B,y=A)) + geom_boxplot() +
  theme_bw()+
  stat_compare_means(aes(label=..p.adj..), comparisons = my_comparisons,
                     label.x = 1.5, label.y = 300)
#  Add p-value
p + stat_compare_means(label.y = 280, label.x = 1.2)
```

[image: plot1]

```
# Change method
p + stat_compare_means(method = "anova", label.y = 260, label.x = 2.2)
```

[image: plot2]

I also recommend the you look at this [post on R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots/)

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UGw4.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oriH8.png
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
but the adjusted p value for multiple comparisons is not displayed when I add the `comparison` parameter in `stat_compare_means`. I'll use an other example.
   


`data("ToothGrowth")`
`my_comparisons <- list( c("0.5", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0.5", "2") )`
`ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", color = "dose", palette = "jco") +   stat_compare_means(aes(label=..p.adj..), comparisons = my_comparisons)`

Comment: @zercchi have you seen the help manual of `?stat_compare_means`. In it the `label` option states, `character string specifying label type. Allowed values include "p.signif" (shows the significance levels), "p.format" (shows the formatted p value).` I think, you need `compare_means()` for it has the `p.adj` option that you are looking for.

Comment: @Ashish: as you pointed out in your comment, your answer is wrong ["stat_compare_means(aes(label=..p.adj..)..." is not possible], so please correct it otherwise it is confusing.